# Repeating linked list value

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a Linked list ,If I insert an object every time then the last value is repeating.Not for the very first insert,but for the next insertion its repeating by 1,6,16.... Please check the below code

Java Code:

```
    List<JSONObject> linkedList = new LinkedList<JSONObject>();

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        double ID =Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("value1"));
        double  age=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("value2"));
        String type=request.getParameter("value5");
        int pre=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("value3"));
        int nxt=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("value4"));
        String config_Feature=request.getParameter("value6");

        try {
            if(config_Feature.equals("insert")) {
                int insertAtIndexForJSONArray = findInsertAtIndex(linkedList,nxt);

                insertValue(insertAtIndexForJSONArray,linkedList,ID,age,type);

                JSONArray alist = new JSONArray(linkedList);
                System.out.println(alist);
                WritingJsonDataToFile(alist);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  

    private static int findInsertAtIndex(List<JSONObject> linkedList2, int i) throws JSONException {
        int curIndex =0;
        int reqIndex=0;
        for(int j=0;j<linkedList2.size();j++){
            JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) linkedList2.get(j);
            if(jo.getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
                if(curIndex==i){
                    reqIndex=j;
                    break;
                }
                curIndex++;
            }
        }
        return reqIndex;
    }

    private static void insertValue(int index, List<JSONObject> linkedList2,double ID,double age,String t) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray ja1= new JSONArray();
        //Copy the data from that index in another JSONArray
        //It is an array, so you will need to do shifting
        for(int i=index;i<linkedList2.size();i++) {
            ja1.put(linkedList2.get(i));
        }
        JSONObject jo  = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jo3 = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("ID", ID);
        jo.put("Age", age);
        jo3.put("type", t);
        jo3.put("DB", jo);
        linkedList2.add(index, jo3);

        int shiftIndex = index+1;
        for(int i=0;i<ja1.length();i++) {
            linkedList2.add(shiftIndex,(JSONObject) ja1.get(i));
            shiftIndex++;
        }
    }
```

O/P for the 1st insertion

```
[{"DB":{"ID":1239,"Age":55},"type":"L"}]
For 2nd insertion 
 [{"DB":{"ID":1233,"Age":45},"type":"L"},{"DB":{"ID":1239,"Age":55},"type":"L"},{"DB":{"ID":1239,"Age":55},"type":"L"}]
For 3rd insertion 
[{"DB":{"ID":1233,"Age":45},"type":"L"},{"DB":{"ID":10010,"Age":22},"type":"s"},{"DB":{"ID":1239,"Age":55},"type":"L"},{"DB":{"ID":1239,"Age":55},"type":"L"},{"DB":{"ID":1239,"Age":55},"type":"L"},{"DB":{"ID":1239,"Age":55},"type":"L"}]
```

Comment: Please minimize your code to minimal compilable code that still shows the problem, as there is a wall of code in here that is unlikely to be read by anyone, and is basically looking for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: what is the I/P you are giving?

Comment: input will be from html page

Comment: also i think your code will not compile because of try-catch block, wrong blocking

Comment: No I am able to compile please check the o/p that  I have written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `insertValue()`, first, you copy the linked list elements into a json array, then you add the new element to the linked list and **then again** you add the firstly copied elements... which are already in the linkedlist.

A `LinkedList` handles the insertion of elements for you (that's the purpose of using collections). You don't need to *shift* anything or to copy yourself.

For illustration, on a `LinkedList<String>`,

```
// if linkedlist contains ["a", "b", "s"]
linkedlist.add(2, "X");
// linkedlist contains now ["a", "b", "X", "c"]
```

The method should be something like (I haven't compiled it):

```
private static void insertValue(int index, List<JSONObject> linkedList2,
                                double ID, double age, String t) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jo1  = new JSONObject();
    jo1.put("ID", ID);
    jo1.put("Age", age);
    JSONObject jo2 = new JSONObject();
    jo2.put("type", t);
    jo2.put("DB", jo1);
    linkedList2.add(index, jo2);
}
```

Comment: I'm happy for that. Don't forget to validate/upvote the answer.